# me salta un “IndentationError: expected an indented block”

Tags: python

Me salta un:

> “IndentationError: expected an indented block”

```
def impar(x) :
 if x % 2 == 1:
   print("%d es impar" % x)

rdd.foreach(impar)
```

Comment: esto en qué se relaciona con MySQL?

Comment: def impar (x):.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: nada solo con python perdon soy nuevo

Comment: esto no es html O.o

Comment: Tres etiquetas y no coincide ninguna. Un premio por favor XD

Comment: Paciencia señores

Comment: Es usuario nuevo tratemos de explicarle como funciona el sitio y sus errores para que los vaya corrigiendi, aunque si @JDev quedé perplejo con las etiquetas xD!

Comment: @gbianchi Si, no hay problema :)

Comment: Listo, me desdigo, el codigo estaba identado en la pregunta original.

Comment: te recomiendo leer algo de buenas practicas @GuidoBenicio https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Hola Guido, es importante que agregues el código a la pregunta exactamente como lo tienes tú. Solo tienes que ir al botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/175916/edit) que hay debajo de ella, lo copias y pegas, luego seleccionas todo el código pegado y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor o `Ctrl` + `k` para que se formatee como código y no se pierda la identación. El error se debe a un mal identado del código, pero como está actualmente el código este error no es posible. Usa siempre cuatro espacios entre niveles de identación y no mezcles  tabulaciones y espacios.Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos y sobre todo por la paciencia

Comment: @GuidoBenicio el error es simple, la identacion es incorrecta; estas usando en algunos casos enter y en otras la barra espaciadora